# add lines to the apache2 confing

Tags: linux, apache2

I need to add this to my apache2.conf in my VPS:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
extension=mysql.so

extension=memcache.so

extension=mbstring.so

extension=gd.so

extension=mcrypt
```

After I add this and save the apache.conf, and trying to restart the apache, i get an error - Failed.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find that error because you put php directives in apache.

Comment: So where i need to put this lines? in the guide write "Next we want to edit your apache2.conf".

Comment: You have to add/active this extensions in your php.ini not in your apache.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these lines in php.in file.

you can find php.ini file location using,

```
#php -i | grep php.ini
```